# Replace DataFrame from other one dataframe with not same shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one DataFrame with shape (20,4350), I want to put each value from this DataFrame in an other dataframe of shape (20,5000) (filled by 0) and replace each empty value by 0.

I try to do use combine_first , Dataframe.add(). but every time i get a (20,9350) shape.

Any one with a better solution to keep shape (20,5000) and filled by the Dataframe of (20,4350) ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: try this `new_df.iloc[:,0:4350]=old_df`

Comment: So let's say DataFrame with Shape (20,4350) is old_df, new_df is the one with shape (20,500) : 
'new_df=new_df.iloc[:,0:4350]=old_df '
works perfectly as I expected.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let create some dummy data first

```
import pandas as pd
# intialise data of lists. 
old = {'Col1':[1, 2, 3, 4], 'Col2':[20, 21, 19, 18], 'Col3':[10,20,30,40]} 
# Create DataFrame 
old_df = pd.DataFrame(old)
```

Create another data frame with 0 value

```
new={'Col1':[0, 0, 0, 0], 'Col2':[0,0,0,0], 'Col3':[0,0,0,0], 'Col4':[0,0,0,0]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new)
```

Now replace the 0 in a new data frame with values in old data frame

```
new_df.iloc[:,0:3]=old_df
```

In your case it will be

```
new_df.iloc[:,0:4350]=old_df
```